# How to use set Value instead of getUid in FirebaseDatabase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase authentication and database.In my project user sign in and sign up with their email and password.I use a model class where i have three variable email,password and name.I can store email in authentication sector and users details in database.
code is given below:

```
 User user = new User(name,mail,password);
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
   .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
   .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           if (task.isSuccessful()){
               startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this,Home.class));
               finish();
           }else {
               Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Getting error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
```

[image]

Is there any way that i used user name instead of getUid value?like this
[image]

Comment: So you want to have the userName under Users node instead of the uid, right?

Comment: right but i have no knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, instead of passing the uid (`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`) of the user to the `child()` method, pass the `userName`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(name).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
//                                                         ^  ^
```

See I have passed the name instead of the uid.

Comment: it's work but crashed and said Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.webforest.testing.Done.onCreate(Done.java:62)

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. The fact that you are getting another error, it means that the initial issue is solved and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using an object that has the value of `null` but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set like below: replace `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` with `name`. It will create node with userName.

```
user = new User(name,mail,password);
                       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                       .child(name) // replace the getUid() code with name
                       .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                               if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                   startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this,Home.class));
                                   finish();
                               }else {
                                   Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Getting error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           }
```

Hope it will help you:)